# Xperience Reset Banno API

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

When we are entering in the API information into Banno interface in Xperience. It will not allow the public key to save. Were do we have to have the public key from? Any workstation or the Xp server? Also, What are the command prompts to generate the public key in .pem format.

Created Public Key on workstation. Banno would not save the Create external application.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different parts to your questions, so here's the breakdown.

> When we are entering in the API information into Banno interface in Xperience. It will not allow the public key to save.

The UI for creating an *External Application* for the *Admin API* in *Banno Users & Groups* that uses the *Service account* (signed JWT) client credentials flow will verify that the *public key* is entered in *.pem* format.

If the *public key* is not in *.pem* format, then the UI will not let you move forward with creating the *External Application*.

> Were do we have to have the public key from? Any workstation or the Xp server?

The *public key* (and its paired *private key*) can be generated on any workstation. There is no requirement to use the Xperience server to generate the *public key*. You certainly *could* use the Xperience server, but you could also use your laptop. It's up to you how you want to define and execute a process for managing the *public+private key* pair.

> Also, What are the command prompts to generate the public key in .pem format.

The steps to generate a *public key + private key* pair, in *.pem format*, from the command line are documented in [Public Key + Private Key](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/overview/authentication/publickey-privatekey/). Those steps use the `openssl` tool (which is available for various operating systems).

The *.pem* file is a text file that can be opened with any text editor. (You may have configure your text editor to open *.pem* formatted files, though.)

> Created Public Key on workstation. Banno would not save the Create external application.

While your question is focused on setting up the Xperience app to use Banno's Admin API, it probably is useful to go through the [Authentication - Client Credentials (Command Line)](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/quickstarts/authentication/) quickstart tutorial.

Going through those steps will give you the pieces you need to access the Admin API. Those pieces (especially the *public key in .pem format*) will be useful in configuring the Xperience app to use the Admin API.